# How to not specify default parameters in python?

Tags: python, function, syntax

I'm working with a python package (MySQLdb). The connect method has lots of positional parameters, most of which have defaults, but some aren't easy to deduce.

How can I only specify the parameters I want?

i.e. if a connect method has the following signature:

```
connect(username, password, socket, timeout)
```

and `socket` has a default value which may be system-dependent

is it possible to invoke it with something like the following so I don't overwrite the default value for `socket`:

```
connect('tom', 'passwd12', , 3)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
connect(username='tom', password='passwd12', timeout=3)
```

For more information please see [Using Optional and Named Arguments](http://diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/optional_arguments.html).

Comment: http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#mysqldb seems to suggest that most are positional, not keyword params though

Comment: @petraus: if you read down that page you'll see exact same code as posted in the answers.

Comment: thanks for the link. must have missed that when i read the book.

Comment: @SilentGhost - oh yeah, i didn't see that :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use keyword arguments rather than positional parameters in this case. 
As is obvious

```
connect ('tom', 'passwd12, None, 3)
```

is a lot less understandable than

```
connect (username = 'tom',
         password = 'passwd12',
         timeout = 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

the MySQLdb-python source says this about connect:

"It is strongly recommended that you only use keyword parameters."